# Как на Python реализовать Telegram бота на WebHook?

Tags: python, python-3.x, webhook, aiogram-3.x

Библиотека [Aiogram3](https://docs.aiogram.dev/en/dev-3.x/index.html), не могу реализовать бота с **Вебхуками**. В документации нет того что мне нужно, методы такие как ***set_webhook*** и т.д. не работают, или я не знаю как ими пользоваться. Если есть тот кто знает как в новом *Aiogram3* сделать вебхуки на локальной машине то буду очень благодарен.

Comment: вебхуки будут работать, если веб-сервер имеет сертификат и позволяет подключаться по https.

Comment: Есть ли какие-то утилиты для получения сертификата бесплатно?

Answer (score 0):

```
import logging
import uvicorn
from aiogram.fsm.storage.memory import MemoryStorage

from fastapi import FastAPI
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, types

from src import load_config
from src.tgbot.handlers.user.start import start_router

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logging.basicConfig(
    level=logging.INFO,
    format=u'%(filename)s:%(lineno)d #%(levelname)-8s [%(asctime)s] - %(name)s - %(message)s',
)

config = load_config(".env")

WEBHOOK_PATH = f"/bot/{config.tg.token}"
WEBHOOK_URL = config.tg.webhook_url + WEBHOOK_PATH

app = FastAPI()
bot = Bot(token=config.tg.token, parse_mode="HTML")
storage = MemoryStorage()
dp = Dispatcher(storage=storage)


@app.on_event("startup")
async def on_startup():
    webhook_info = await bot.get_webhook_info()
    if webhook_info != WEBHOOK_URL:
        await bot.set_webhook(url=WEBHOOK_URL)
    logger.info("Bot started")


dp.include_router(start_router)


@app.post(WEBHOOK_PATH)
async def bot_webhook(update: dict):
    telegram_update = types.Update(**update)
    await dp.feed_update(bot=bot, update=telegram_update)


@app.on_event("shutdown")
async def on_shutdown():
    await bot.session.close()
    logger.info("Bot stopped")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn.run(app, host="0.0.0.0", port=8000)
```

Шаблон бота на вебхуке с использованием сервера uvicorn + fastAPI

Для запуска на локальной машине необходимо установить утилиту ngrok

Ссылка на репозиторий [github](https://github.com/trafi713/aopgram3_template_fastAPI)

Comment: Можно ли использовать похожим образом Aiogram-dev 3 и можно ли без Ngrok с белым ip, просто вставить ip в webhook_url из конфига и всё?

Comment: cfg:
WEBHOOK_URL=https://static_ip
==========================

INFO:     Started server process [9260]
INFO:     Waiting for application startup.
main.py:33 #INFO     [2023-04-15 22:35:55,122] - __main__ - Bot started
INFO:     Application startup complete.
INFO:     Uvicorn running on http://0.0.0.0:8000 (Press CTRL+C to quit)
==============================================

Бот не отвечает на сообщения но вроде запускается

Comment: Он не получает апдейты, вы указали домен в .env?

Comment: Да, я указал свой домен с Regru

Comment: Для локального запуска нужен домен ngrok

Comment: Зачем когда у меня есть свой сервер

Comment: @Nurlashka подними nginx на своем сервере, который будет слушать твой сайт и перенаправлять запросы, которые делаются к сайту непосредственно в fastapi. А сам fastapi запускай на своем сервере с хостом localhost

Answer (score 0):

так, допустим, у нас есть сайт уже с https, например, testsite.ru. https-сертификат можно сгенерировать с помощью lets encrypt либо на req.ru бесплатный на какой-то срок выдают, только домен купите

и есть у нас код, например, main.py

```
import toml
import fastapi
import uvicorn

from typing import Any
from pathlib import Path
from fastapi import FastAPI
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, types
from aiogram.enums.parse_mode import ParseMode


config: dict = toml.load(Path(__file__).parent.with_name("config.toml"))

app = FastAPI()

bot = Bot(
    token=config["telegram"]["bot_token"],
    parse_mode=ParseMode.HTML,
    disable_web_page_preview=True
)

dp = Dispatcher()


@app.on_event("startup")
async def on_startup() -> None:
    webhook_url = f"{config['webhook']['domain']}{config['webhook']['path']}"
    webhook_info = await bot.get_webhook_info()
    if webhook_info.url != webhook_url:
        await bot.set_webhook(
            url=webhook_url,
            # allowed_updates=["message", "callback_query"]
        )


@app.post(config["webhook"]["path"])
async def webhook(update: dict[str, Any]) -> None:
    await dp.feed_webhook_update(bot=bot, update=types.Update(**update))


@app.on_event("shutdown")
async def on_shutdown() -> None:
    await bot.session.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn.run(app, host="127.0.0.1", port=9999, loop="uvloop")
```

Файл config.toml

```
[telegram]
bot_token = "1452359:ewfoiwefjoijsf"

[webhook]
path = "/bot/1452359:ewfoiwefjoijsf"
domain = "https://testsite.ru"
# domain = "https://aaaa-185-90-170.ngrok-free.app"
```

сверху закомментировал адрес ngrok.
как работает ngrok:

1. Пишем сообщение боту
2. Это апдейт -> сервер телеграма отправляет хук на адрес ngrok, то есть aaaa-185
3. ngrok перенаправляет запрос на наш localhost, где запущен fastapi
4. запрос обработан

По факту нам нужно сделать так, чтобы что-то слушало наш сайт (это будет nginx) и перенаправляло запрос на наш fastapi, только fastapi будет работать уже на сервере.

Вернемся. Мы купили сервер. здорово, через консоль подключаемся к нему. либо руками, либо через scp копируем main.py на сервер.

Возможно, прежде чем идти дальше придется настроить ufw. Статья https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-nginx-as-a-reverse-proxy-on-ubuntu-22-04. Попробуйте, если не будет работать

Команда для конфига: `sudo nano /etc/nginx/sites-available/testsite.ru.conf`
Скачиваем nginx на сервер, читаем документацию и пишем в конфиг следующее

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name testsite.ru www.testsite.ru;
    root /var/www/testsite.ru/html;
    index index.html;

    location /webhook {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9999;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    }

    return 301 https://testsite.ru$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name testsite.ru www.testsite.ru;

    root /var/www/testsite.ru/html;
    index index.html;
    charset utf-8;

    location /webhook {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9999;
    }

    location /sendMessage {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9999;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico {
        log_not_found off;
    }

    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/testsite.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/testsite.key;
}
```

а вообще я не понимаю смысла использовать хуки. поллинг сейчас работает, по моим ощущениям, так же. есть смысл только по приколу его сделать, если у вас есть web app. собственно, конфиг на nginx я скопировал для web app со своего сервера. в index.html лежит весь код. если хочется читать из web app сообщения, то вот хендлер для fastapi

```
@app.post("/sendMessage")
async def send_message_handler(request: fastapi.Request) -> None:
    """TODO"""
    print("Зашел в send-message-handler")
```

а в index.html положите базовый пример отсюда https://github.com/revenkroz/telegram-web-app-bot-example/blob/master/index.html. Я вырезал все ненужное и оставил только кнопку sendMessage

вот код:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <meta name="google-site-verification" content="t_mnRNlgwBIpMX1qv7z4wBOQM4Q4">
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="MobileOptimized" content="176" />
    <meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="True" />
    <meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow" />
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://telegram.org/js/telegram-web-app.js?1"></script>
    <script>
        function setThemeClass() {
            document.documentElement.className = Telegram.WebApp.colorScheme;
        }
        Telegram.WebApp.onEvent('themeChanged', setThemeClass);
        setThemeClass();
    </script>
    <style>
        body {
            --bg-color: var(--tg-theme-bg-color, #fff);
            font-family: sans-serif;
            background-color: var(--bg-color);
            color: var(--tg-theme-text-color, #222);
            font-size: 14px;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            color-scheme: var(--tg-color-scheme);
        }

                a {
            color: var(--tg-theme-link-color, #2678b6);
        }

        button {
            display: block;
            width: 100%;
            font-size: 14px;
            margin: 15px 0;
            padding: 12px 20px;
            border: none;
            border-radius: 4px;
            background-color: var(--tg-theme-button-color, #50a8eb);
            color: var(--tg-theme-button-text-color, #ffffff);
            cursor: pointer;
        }
        .main-container {
            padding: 15px;
        }

        .main-container p {
            margin: 0 0 10px;
        }
        .main-container pre,
        .main-container > .btn {
            margin: 0 0 7px;
        }
        .main-container pre + .hint,
        .main-container > .btn + .hint {
            text-align: center;
            margin: 0 0 15px;
        }
                button[disabled] {
            opacity: 0.6;
            cursor: auto;
            pointer-events: none;
        }

        button.close_btn {
            /*position: fixed;*/
            position: absolute;
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            border-radius: 0;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 16px 20px;
            text-transform: uppercase;
        }

        input[type="text"]::-webkit-input-placeholder {
            color: var(--tg-theme-hint-color, #ccc);
        }
        input[type="text"]::-moz-placeholder {
            color: var(--tg-theme-hint-color, #ccc);
        }
        input[type="text"]:-ms-input-placeholder {
            color: var(--tg-theme-hint-color, #ccc);
        }
               section {
            padding: 15px;
            text-align: center;
            background-color: var(--bg-color, #ffffff);
        }
        section#top_sect {
            background-color: var(--tg-theme-bg-color, #ffffff);
        }
        section#top_sect.second {
            background-color: var(--tg-theme-secondary-bg-color, #efefef);
        }
        section .sect_row {
            margin: 10px 0;
        }
        section + section {
            padding: 0 15px 65px;
        }
        p {
            margin: 40px 0 15px;
        }
        ul {
            text-align: left;
        }
        li {
            color: var(--tg-theme-hint-color, #a8a8a8);
        }
        textarea {
            width: 100%;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            padding: 7px;
        }
                pre {
            background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .07);
            color: var(--tg-theme-text-color, #222);
            font-size: 12px;
            border: none;
            border-radius: 4px;
            padding: 8px;
            margin: 7px 0;
            word-break: break-word;
            white-space: pre-wrap;
            text-align: left;
        }
        .dark pre {
            background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .15);
        }
        .columns>* {
            flex-grow: 1;
        }
        .hint {
            font-size: .8em;
            color: var(--tg-theme-hint-color, #a8a8a8);
        }
        .ok {
            color: green;
        }
        .err {
            color: red;
        }
        .status_need {
            display: none;
        }
                #fixed_wrap {
            position: fixed;
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
            top: 0;
            transform: translateY(100vh);
        }
        .viewport-container .main-container {
            position: absolute;
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
            top: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
        }
        .viewport-container .main-container button {
            width: auto;
        }

        small {
            font-size: 12px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body class="">

<section id="top_sect" class="second">
    <button id="main_btn" onclick="App.sendMessage('');">Send «Hello, World!»</button>
</section>
<section>
    <div id="btn_status" class="hint" style="display: none;">
    </div>
</section>

<script type="application/javascript">
    const App = {
        initData: Telegram.WebApp.initData || '',
        initDataUnsafe: Telegram.WebApp.initDataUnsafe || {},
        MainButton: Telegram.WebApp.MainButton,

        init(options) {
            Telegram.WebApp.ready();
        },
        expand() {
            Telegram.WebApp.expand();
        },

        close() {
            Telegram.WebApp.close();
        },

        sendMessage(msg_id, with_webview) {
            if (!App.initDataUnsafe.query_id) {
                alert('WebViewQueryId not defined');
                return;
            }

            document.querySelectorAll('button').forEach((btn) => btn.disabled = true);

            App.apiRequest('sendMessage', {
                msg_id: msg_id || '',
                with_webview: !App.initDataUnsafe.receiver && with_webview ? 1 : 0
            }, function (result) {
                document.querySelectorAll('button').forEach((btn) => btn.disabled = false);
            });
        },

        checkInitData() {
            if (App.initDataUnsafe.query_id && App.initData) {
                App.apiRequest('checkInitData', {}, function(result) {
                    if (result.ok) {
                    } else {
                    }
                });
}
        },

        // Other
        apiRequest(method, data, onCallback) {
            const authData = App.initData || '';
            alert(App.initData);
            fetch('/sendMessage', {
                method: 'POST',
                body: JSON.stringify(Object.assign(data, {
                    _auth: authData,
                    method: method,
                })),
                credentials: 'include',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                }
            }).then(function(response) {
                return response.json();
            }).then(function(result) {
                onCallback && onCallback(result);
            }).catch(function(error) {
                onCallback && onCallback({error: 'Server error'});
            });
        }
    }
</script>
<script type="application/javascript">
    /*
     * This part of code is used to initialize the demo app and set up the even>
     */

    if (App.initDataUnsafe.query_id) {
        document.getElementById('main_btn').style.display = 'block';
    }

    App.checkInitData();
    App.init();

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

либо настраиваем systemd, либо просто запускаем main.py. Если не работает, то где-то нужно подправить: смотрите где я что импортирую и делайте там файлы, например, в конфиге nginx есть адреса к https-ключам, их туда нужно положить, что логично. Пример рабочий